# How come methods become unbound when they're returned from a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript

```js
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        this.prop = 5;
    }
    MethA() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.prop);
    }
    MethB() {
        (true ? this.MethA : null)();
    }
}
Test = new TestClass();
Test.MethB();
```

Why does this code fail when reaching `(this.prop)` in `MethA` from the ternary operator in `MethB`?

```
VM:6 undefined
VM:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined
    at MethA (<anonymous>:7:26)
    at TestClass.MethB (<anonymous>:10:35)
    at <anonymous>:14:6
```

---

To preempt any further comments about the `null` in what is clearly a demonstrative example:

In the real code, the condition of the ternary operator is a variable flag, and the false value is another method. The benefit to this structure is that the two functions can share a single argument list that only has to be written once and doesn't need a name.

No, moving the calls to inside the ternary operator doesn't answer this question. It loses the benefit of only needing to write the arguments once, and it's also side effect abuse.

The real solution is to replace the ternary with an `if {} else {}` for side effects, or wrap the methods in arrow functions for a value expression. But that doesn't answer this question either: The point isn't what code could achieve a similar result, as that would be easy; The point is *why* this code doesn't work and what underlying language quirks are the cause of that.

Comment: Have you tried to change `(true ? this.MethA : null)();` to `(true ? this.MethA() : null);`?

Comment: Why is there a ternary there anyway? If there were a real condition instead of a hard-coded true, you'd get an error about `null` not being a method. You're better off collecting the method reference, then executing it if it's good (e.g., `const ref = (true ? this.MethA : null); if (typeof ref === 'function') ref.call(this);`)

Comment: @B001ᛦ That would be side effect abuse. In my actual project, there's an argument list that I want to only write once for both methods, and pass to a different method depending on the condition.

Comment: `this.MethA` returns the function without the context (`this`) and when it's invoked without the context we lose `prop`

Comment: Well you could turn `MethA` and `MethB` into [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to get around the issue. But you still run into the problem that `null` isn't a method when your condition fails

Comment: @HereticMonkey or even more simply `if (cond) this.MethA();`

Comment: @WillChen "*That would be side effect abuse.*" more than using a conditional operator to get a function reference and invoke it?! If you're held at a gunpoint and *absolutely* have to do a conditional method execution as part of an expression, then executing the method immediately is the more correct thing. Hopefully, nobody holds a gun to your head, so you don't actually have to write this kind of code, though.

Comment: "*what underlying language quirks are the cause of that*" it's just how the value of `this` works. Check the duplicate links.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, it would. Getting references to different properties based a condition is the entire point of a conditional operator— [It doesn't matter whether the values are functions or numbers or whatever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen), and as the conditional operator is itself just an expression, it doesn't matter whether you add multiply or call or do anything else to them either. Calling the functions inside the conditional operator, however, breaks that model (and means writing the argument list twice)... Plus relying on lazy evaluation to avoid running both paths.

Comment: @WillChen I'm well aware that functions are first-class objects. I'm also well aware that you shouldn't be using this with *methods*. For reasons that you've found out by trying it and getting an error. It's *functions* that are first-class, methods are functions with a `this` value. Said value is determined at call time. Which feats neatly into the whole ecosystem, as you then need *less* function objects floating around, instances can share a single one and calling `a.m()` or `b.m()` determines whether you get `this = a` or `this = b` when the function is called.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure. That would have been a much more useful and decent response than a rant about me being held at gunpoint. In some dynamic languages (namely Python), methods *are* wrapped into first class objects— hence the question, and the "language quirks".

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the way *scope* works in JavaScript, specifically how the value of `this` is bound.

The main thing to understand is that (in general) when you invoke a function, `this` is *set to the object on which the method was invoked*.

```js
wookie.eatBanana(); // inside the eatBanana method, this === wookie
```

But if you invoke the method separately from the object, `this` ends up being `undefined`:

```js
const detachedFn = wookie.eatBanana;

// same function, but now this === undefined
detachedFn();
```

And what you're doing with `this.MethA` in the ternary effectively detaches it from "this". It's effectively doing this:

```js
MethB() {
  const method = true ? this.MethA : null;
  method(); // invoked standalone, so "this" is undefined inside MethA.
}
```

There are a variety of ways around this if that's not the desired behavior.

Arrow functions inherit the current scope, so if you change MethA to an arrow function you'll notice this issue goes away:

```js
MethA = () => {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.prop);
}

const method = this.MethA;
method(); // this is fine, because arrow functions are bound to the scope in which they are declared
```

Or you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to specify the scope explicitly:

```js
const method = this.MethA.bind(this); // new function pre-bound to 'this'
MethA.call(this); // invoke with a specific scope
MethA.apply(this); // same as above; handles args a bit differently
```